# Java: A public method inherited from superclass invokes a private method.

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, private

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      Student s = new Student();
      s.printPerson();
  }
}

class Person{
  private String getInfo(){
      return "Person";
  }
  public void printPerson(){
      System.out.println(getInfo());
  }
}

class Student extends Person{
  private String getInfo(){
      return "Student";
  }
}
```

The output is `Person`. I am confused with this result. In the main method, the reference type is `Student`. So when executing `s.printPerson()`, it should executes the method of `Student`. The key point is, in the public method inherited from superclass, which private method is invoked? And why?

I thought in `s.printPerson()`, it invokes `getInfo()` of `Student`. But it turns out not. The IDE tells me

```
private String getInfo(){
      return "Student";
}
```

is never used.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: If I call `getInfo()` from class `Person`, I understand that it outputs "Person". But in my code, I call `getInfo()` from class `Student`, not `Person`. I call `getInfo()` from `Student`, it seems to invoke `printPerson()` method of `Person`, not `Student`.  I am confused with this issue.

Comment: I modify the code a little bit. I override `getInfo()` in `Student` with exactly the same code in `Person`. Now the output is "Student". I am wondering about the mechanism of inheriting methods. I thought the output should be the same because whether I override `getInfo()` or not, the content of the method is the same, so the output should be the same. Is there anybody could help me with this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, [`private` methods are not inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

> A subclass does not inherit the `private` members of its parent class.  However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

You cannot override `getInfo` by creating another `getInfo` method because it's not inherited.  That's why your IDE gave you the "never used" warning, because nothing in `Student` uses it.  The `getInfo` from `Person` is called, because it is available to `Person`'s `printPerson` method, so `Person` is printed.

To override a method, it must not be `private`.  You can make `getInfo` package-private (no access modifier), `protected`, or `public`.  Then `Student` will be able to override it.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `private` modifier. This modifier means that the method is only visible from within the class itself, not other classes, not even its sub- and superclasses. So when you call `getInfo()` from class `Person`, the only method visible is the method defined in the `Person` class. Effectively this means that private methods are not inherited in Java.

Try to change the `private` modifier to `protected`. Then the subclasses can see the method from the superclass, and so they can overide the method.

Comment: I think that a method from subclass is never visible in its superclass (not only for private methods). Am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I still do not understand. I call the `getInfo()` method of class `Student` not `Person`. Should it invoke `printPerson()` of class `Student`? More details are in the comments of original post. Thank you.